# Scala sum aggregation issue

Tags: scala, elasticsearch

here is my code which prints toString method of InternalSum and i want actual numeric sum to be print on screen but it's not giving me any further method to retrieve the sum

```
val sumSalary = client.execute {
    search("myindex") aggregations sumAgg("sum_salary_aggregation", "salary")size 0
  }

   sumSalary.map(f => println(f.original.getAggregations.get("sum_salary_aggregation")))
```

output : org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.metrics.sum.InternalSum@2bef9178

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like to you need to call `.value()` on the result.

Specifically:

```
   sumSalary.foreach(f => println(f.aggregations.sumResult("sum_salary_aggregation").value()))
```

Comment: Can you provide some details about what you've tried and what is not working?

Comment: finally i got solution as      
   sumSalary.foreach(f => println(f.aggregations.sumResult("sum_salary_aggregation").value()))